# Mysql JOIN : SELECT only if multiple rows in join match

Tags: mysql, join

I wonder if someone here can help me rephrase this, so that I only get results from `works`  if `works`.`id` + `prod_instruments_id` + `number` are all found in `works_instruments` ?

This is what I have:

```
SELECT 
    `works`.`id`, 
    `composers`.`first_name` 
FROM `works` 
    JOIN `composers` ON `works`.`composers_id` = `composers`.`id` 
    JOIN `works_instruments` ON `works`.`id` = `works_instruments`.`works_id` 
WHERE 
    (true) 
    AND `composers`.`full_name` LIKE '%karl friedrich abel%' 
    AND `works_instruments`.`prod_dd_instruments_id` = 15 
    AND `works_instruments`.`number` >= 1 
    AND `works_instruments`.`prod_dd_instruments_id` = 5 
    AND `works_instruments`.`number` >= 1 
    AND `works`.`work_no` <> '001' AND `works`.`short_title` NOT LIKE '%*Works' 
ORDER BY 
    `composers`.`last_name`, 
    `composers`.`first_name`, 
    `works`.`full_title` 
LIMIT 0,50
```

Right now this returns no results.
However this does:

```
SELECT 
    `works`.`id`, 
    `composers`.`first_name` 
FROM `works` 
    JOIN `composers` ON `works`.`composers_id` = `composers`.`id` 
    JOIN `works_instruments` ON `works`.`id` = `works_instruments`.`works_id` 
WHERE 
    (true) 
    AND `composers`.`full_name` LIKE '%karl friedrich abel%' 
    AND `works_instruments`.`prod_dd_instruments_id` = 15 
    AND `works_instruments`.`number` >= 1 
    AND `works`.`work_no` <> '001' AND `works`.`short_title` NOT LIKE '%*Works' 
ORDER BY 
    `composers`.`last_name`, 
    `composers`.`first_name`, 
    `works`.`full_title` 
LIMIT 0,50
```

And this does:

```
SELECT 
    `works`.`id`, 
    `composers`.`first_name` 
FROM `works` 
    JOIN `composers` ON `works`.`composers_id` = `composers`.`id` 
    JOIN `works_instruments` ON `works`.`id` = `works_instruments`.`works_id` 
WHERE 
    (true) 
    AND `composers`.`full_name` LIKE '%karl friedrich abel%'  
    AND `works_instruments`.`prod_dd_instruments_id` = 5 
    AND `works_instruments`.`number` >= 1 
    AND `works`.`work_no` <> '001' AND `works`.`short_title` NOT LIKE '%*Works' 
ORDER BY 
    `composers`.`last_name`, 
    `composers`.`first_name`, 
    `works`.`full_title` 
LIMIT 0,50
```

Can you help?

I also tried LEFT and RIGHT join, but still an empty result (I am only pasting LEFT here):

```
SELECT 
    `works`.`id`, 
    `composers`.`first_name` 
FROM `works` 
    JOIN `composers` ON `works`.`composers_id` = `composers`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `works_instruments` ON `works`.`id` = `works_instruments`.`works_id` 
WHERE 
    (true) 
    AND `composers`.`full_name` LIKE '%karl friedrich abel%' 
    AND `works_instruments`.`prod_dd_instruments_id` = 15 
    AND `works_instruments`.`number` >= 1 
    AND `works_instruments`.`prod_dd_instruments_id` = 5 
    AND `works_instruments`.`number` >= 1 
    AND `works`.`work_no` <> '001' AND `works`.`short_title` NOT LIKE '%*Works' 
ORDER BY 
    `composers`.`last_name`, 
    `composers`.`first_name`, 
    `works`.`full_title` 
LIMIT 0,50
```

Is it a problem that `works_instruments` does not have uniqe IDs?
See Screenshot of `works_instruments` here:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNHRa.png)

Comment: Rather than pictures, setting something up at sqlfiddle.com will make it much easier for people to try getting you an answer.

Comment: ok - thanks. I'll keep this in mind next time. Havent tried it before - but I'll figure it out.

Comment: Pretty simple, just use the schema window to CREATE TABLE(s) and  INSERT some data. Then use the query window to run your query, and include the link in your question. Most importantly, it lets people try out different things, and see what the table(s) really looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no numeric value where a field can = 15 and = 5 at the same time. Instead, you could do "IN (15, 5)", group by works.id, and count the distinct prod_dd_instruments_id values to see if there were two; or do two separate joins two the same table with the differing sets of criteria.

Edit: With the additional info you've given below, something like this might be more helpful.

```
SELECT works.*, composers.*
, SUM(IF(wi.prod_dd_instruments_id=15, wi.number, 0)) AS count15
, SUM(IF(wi.prod_dd_instruments_id=5, wi.number, 0)) AS count5
FROM works 
INNER JOIN `composers` ON `works`.`composers_id` = `composers`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `works_instruments` AS wi ON `works`.`id` = wi.`works_id`
WHERE [the other criteria you had]
GROUP BY works.id
HAVING count15 > 1 AND count5 > 1
;
```

Note that this query only works for "5 & 15"; though (judging from your "`(true)`" I am hazarding a guess you are constructing the query at lease partially in code, so I would think it would not be too difficult to make the above a little more flexible with code.

Comment: Thank you. This sounds promising - however, Im not sure how to actually do it. Note that I am also looking for `works_instruments`.`number` : `works_instruments`.`number` >= 1 ... I can use IN (5,15) to ask for `prod_instruments_id` - but how do I also ask for `number` in?

Comment: @JohnK According to the OP, currently you are just checking `number >= 1` twice. Also, JOINing the table twice is probably better than joining with an `IN`; an `IN` is a thinly guised `OR`, and `OR`s generally kill any index benefits you might have in MySQL.

Comment: Yes, I also just realized that I am checking number twice. Which makes things even more complicated - because the reason I was checking number twice is: I meant to check if there is 1 or more of instrument 5 and 1 or more of instrument 15. I guess that probably changes things quite a bit. I will need to add a unique index to `works_instruments`, right? So that number and instrument can relate to the same index. And then.... I dont know.... :-(

Comment: @JohnK With the information given so far, there doesn't seem to be a need for any uniqueness indexes; though if you are intending only one row in works_instruments for each `prod_dd_instruments_id` and `works_id` pairing, one wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you so much. And you are right; 5 and 15 are actually variables. But I'll play around with your suggestion.